# SQL Refer to Column on Right Side of SET Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Is the following valid in SQL (theoretical)?

```
UPDATE Classes
SET bore = bore * 2.5;
```

I can't find a source that says whether this is valid or not.

This should multiply every entry in the bore attribute by 2.5. If not, is there a way to multiply a column by a scalar and update?

Comment: As the others have pointed out that usage is fine, just be aware that MySQL does not work correctly if you use the same column multiple times, e.g to swap column values: `update foo set x = y, y = x` will **not** work in MySQL (but will in essentially every other DBMS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL is correct, see the SQL fiddle example on the link below. It creates the table, inserts some values and updates the table with your SQL.

[See this SQL fiddle for example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c357/2)

Comment: Thanks for linking that SQL fiddle, didn't know that existed to try things out.

Comment: You're welcome, it's a great way to do some quick tests. I put together that fiddle right now to test your SQL. I updated the fiddle url btw, not sure which fiddle you opened. They did the same, but I used your table/column names in the last link.

Answer (score 1):

It's valid and correct. You're assigning to each row of `bore` column a new value, multiplying the current value by 2.5. This is perfectly fine in the [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) statement.
The MySQL documentation has a similar example:

> If you access a column from the table to be updated in an expression,
>   UPDATE uses the current value of the column. For example, the following statement sets col1 > to one more than its current value:

```
UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1;
```

You can then suppose that this is valid.